# Single-line Linux command to list symlinks, targets and target dates?

Tags: linux, file, command, find, symlink

Is there a way I can generate a list of symlinks in a directory that includes the target's date, symlink's name and the target's name separated by a specified delimiter?

Either of these gives me only the target date and link name:

`find -L /path/to/dir/* -printf "%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS|%p\n"`

`ls -lH /path/to/dir/*`

This...

`find /path/to/dir/* -printf "%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS|%p|%l\n"`

...I get the *link* date, link name and target name.  `%l` returns nothing if I include the `-L' parameter, I guess because I guess it loses it's reference when it follows the link.

How can get the **link date**, **link name** and **target name** from a one line command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `-exec` switch of `find` to execute another command (like `stat`) on the results making it possible to get properties of the target files.

Example:

`find /path/to/dir/* -printf "%T@|%p|%l" -exec stat -Lc "|%Y.0000000000" {} \;`

This should output something like:

`Link Date|Link Name|Target Name|Target Date`

You might want to play around with the date format strings to make the dates more human readable.

Comment: Thanks, that's very close to what I'm looking for.  I just wasn't sure what other command I could call.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final command I'm using, thanks largely to **rc0r**:

`find /path/to/files/* -printf "%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS|%p|%l" -exec stat -Lc "|%y" {} \; | sed -r "s/(.*\|)([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{9}).*/\1\2\3\4\5\6\7/g"`

Augmentations to **r0cr's** command:

1. Formatted `find -printf` to give human-readable timestamp instead of Unix timestamp
2. Used `%y` instead of `%Y` in `stat` to give human-readable timestamp instead of Unix timestamp
3. Piped `sed` to strip extraneous characters from human-readable timestamp output by `stat`

This gives me:

`SymlinkDate|SymlinkPath|TargetPath|TargetDate`

The dates are in human readable format: `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.mmmmmmmmm`

I don't imagine having `sed` all those back refrences is the most efficient method of stripping chars out of the target date, but I couldn't figure out any other regexp for extracting only [0-9\.].  Efficiency isn't terribly important for this particular implementation.

Thank-you!